# What is the Difference Between Retrieve & RetrieveMultiple in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

What is the Difference Between Retrieve & RetrieveMultiple in Dynamics CRM?
I know that RetrieveMultiple return Multiple records but need to know other differences and the advantages/disadvantages of using them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Retrieve` retrieves a single record given the record ID, the method requires 3 parameters: the entity logicalname, the record ID and the columns (attributes) you want to retrieve.
It throws an exception if the record ID is not found.

`RetrieveMultiple` runs a Query against CRM, normally a `QueryExpression` is used that defines the entity logicalname, the conditions of the query and the columns (attributes) you want to retrieve.
It returns always an `EntityCollection` object and the `Entities` property contains the list of the records that satisfy the query conditions, so you can have 0, 1 or n records returned.